# How to use aggregate functions on groupby and turn it into dataframe?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of defaulted clients and their debt amounts, credit loans. The df has 558 entries, but only 350 unique clients.
I want to group by and plot all kind of charts- build a typical "bad" client profile. I need to group by client id. A customer may have several defaulted loans.

```
clients = df_defaulted.groupby(['client_id'])
```

but it's not a df, it's a groupby object! How to use agg and other functions to get insights and plot charts? I only have drawn basic charts and they include repeating clients data - distribution by age, loan amount. there is repeating data crippling in my charts.

How to turn to normal df a groupby object and use aggregate functions?

Comment: Can you share 'copy-pastable' version of sample data?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the apply or agg function on top of your groupby objects.

Something like:

```
df_defaulted.groupby(['client_id'])['debt amounts'].sum()
df_defaulted.groupby(['client_id']).agg(Bad_Debet_Count=('client_id', 'size')
```

Without saying your data, it's hard to help you further.